# Configuration Of JMS Connection Factories For Spring Batch Partitioning On JBoss 5.2

Tags: spring, integration, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am trying to integrate Spring Batch / Spring Integration with JBoss 5.2 using JBoss Messaging. I am currently access the connection factory using a JNDI lookup of a connection factory defined in the jms-ds.xml.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="springbatch.jmsConnectionFactory" jndi-name="${springbatch.partition.jms.connectionFactoryName}"/>
```

With logging at a normal level, it appears to start and work fine (most of the time). I turned up the logging to identify a problem with connections to JMS systems failing and I am seeing this exception in the server.log file

```
2014-12-29 10:16:26,396 DEBUG [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] (HDScanner) Registering job: partitioned.job.1
2014-12-29 10:16:26,416 DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper] (HDScanner) Method [public java.util.Collection org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler.handle(org.springframework.batch.core.partition.StepExecutionSplitter,org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution) throws java.lang.Exception] is not eligible for Message handling.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found more than one parameter type candidate: [org.springframework.batch.core.partition.StepExecutionSplitter] and [org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:89)
```

Based on some other posting, I tried wrapping the JNDI returned Connection Factory with a SingleConnectionFactory and have the same results.

What is the recommended way to configure the connection factories for partitioned spring batch jobs on JBoss?

Answer (score 0):

That's a DEBUG message while Spring Integration is trying to discover eligible methods for the aggregator; it is not an error and can be ignored.

Set the log level for `org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` to INFO to suppress it.